# Running "ngen install EntityFramework.dll" fails with error 0x800706BE and 0x80131F06

Tags: entity-framework, windows-8, ngen

As advised by the [Entity Framework Team](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn582034) I've tried to create a native image of `EntityFramework.dll` with this command:

```
ngen install packages\EntityFramework.6.1.0-beta1\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll
```

this results in the error `0x80131F06` (no native image for mscorlib.dll). When I now try to run `ngen install mscorlib.dll` I get the error `0x800706BE` (RPC_S_CALL_FAILED - The remote procedure call failed).

I already used `sfc /scannow` and it reports no broken files.

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: Not having a native image for mscorlib is very, very bad.  What happened next is just more very, very bad, the ".NET Runtime Optimization Service" bombed.  Ought to be a record of it in the event log.  Or you did something unwise like disabling it.  Your machine is not in good shape, you need the geek squad, not a programmer.

Comment: I also tried to install .net 4.5.1 and hoped that this would fix it, but no chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the issue myself. It is caused by the enabled *DeveloperMode* which was set by *Redgates .NET Reflector VisualStudio Addon*. Disabling it with this entry in the `machine.config` fixed it:

```
  <runtime>
    <developmentMode developerInstallation="false"/>
  </runtime>
```

Now I have a native Image for mscorlib and I can ngen EF.